# Can someone translate me this to english?

Tags: simplified-characters, character-identification

I have an image that is something wrote in chinese I think. Can someone translate it please? Thank you.
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/v1H8R.jpg]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably the transliteration of a name like Micheala， Mikela
迈 mai
克 ke
拉 la

克拉 kela is the transliteration of carat, which for gold represents the purity of the gold. Maybe its the name of a store, or a joke "this is my gold bracelet".

Answer (score 1):

迈克拉 is a English name translated to Chinese.

There are quite a number of English last name could be translated to 迈克拉, by the pronunciation.

For instance, there are quite a number of famous people where their last name translated to 迈克拉:

> 乔丹-**迈克拉**伊 (Jordan **McRae**)  -NBA player

For this case, `迈-Mc 克-c 拉-Ra 伊-e`

> 扎恩·**迈克拉**农 (Zahn **McClarnon**)  -an actor

For this case, `迈-Mc 克-cla 拉-lar 农-non`